# Are there any mature samples of WP7 code available either on codeplex or somewhere?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am looking for some advanced samples of windows phone 7 that use expression blend for UI design and VS 2010 for app development that talks to services etc. and probably uses some frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good tutorials at [Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/windowsphone/index.htm), some of which also explain Blend. Another Blend specific tutorials is [this article](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7GettingStarted/HelloPhoneWP7Lab/Exercise-2-Using-Expression-Blend-to-Design-the-UX-of-your-Windows-Phone-Application). You can also download some WP7 design templates that comply to the Metro UI guidelines over at [CodePlex](http://wp7designtemplates.codeplex.com/).

You can also download code samples over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which has the `Weather Forecast` sample showing how to use web services.

Regarding frameworks, you could look into [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) is quite popular regarding the implementation of MVVM in Silverlight applications. (Articles and tutorials further down the page)

There's a huge resource list [here](http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/windows-phone-7-resources/), although it covers all sorts of aspects, not just advanced samples.

A WP7 book is also being written, which you can download the preview version of [here](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/).